# Open Source Gantt Chart Applications

Tags: open-source, windows-7, project-management

I would like an open source program to create Gantt Charts ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/):

- free and open source
- runs on Windows, Linux and MacOSX
- Gantt Chart

[image]

Comment: @FranckDemoncourt Thankyou for your answers. Shouldn't all 3 applications that you have suggested be incorporated into one single answer, rather than three separate answers ?

Comment: You are welcome, one program per answer for clarity (and to follow this SE guidelines)..

Comment: @FranckDemoncourt Ah ok fine :)

Comment: If you want to export your Gantt chart for presentations etc., GanttProject is rather not the right tool. Its PDF export looks like a screenshot of the UI (vector oriented, at least) with task names cut off both in the list and in the chart …

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GanttPV](http://www.pureviolet.net/ganttpv/):

- free and open source
- runs on Windows, Linux and MacOSX
- Gantt Chart
- scriptable

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OpenProj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/):

- free and open source
- runs on Windows, Linux and MacOSX
- Gantt Chart
- Last release: 2008

[image]

Comment: As per my answer ProjectLibre was forked from OpenProject and is still actively developed.

Answer (score 1):

[ProjectLibre](https://www.projectlibre.com/) was forked from OpenProj in 2012 and is still actively developed, such that they will soon be offering a commercial version. But he OSS version is alive and well, and it what I currently use, mainly for it's MS Project compatibility.

Yes, it does Gantt charts and more besides. It's very functional and capable, even if the interface is dated - boy, you can tell it was developed in Java!

It does the job and the price is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TaskJuggler](http://taskjuggler.org/):

- Free and open source software
- Runs on Linux, Unix, Windows, MacOS etc
- No GUI. Instead, uses a small script / markup language to define the project requirements, and outputs Gantt charts as graphical reports.
- Exports Gantt charts to interactive HTML pages.
- Full project management solution, not just charting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/):

- Free and open source software
- Written in Ruby
- Runs on Linux-based web servers (Apache2), used with a web browser on any OS
- Sophisticated: [>31,000 commits](https://github.com/opf/openproject), and still in active development.
- It's a full project management solution mostly meant for software projects.
- Gantt charts are called "[Timelines](https://www.openproject.org/#timelines)" there.

**Caveat:** There is no dedicated feature to export the Gantt chart as PDF, SVG or any other format to include in a document. So you'll have to either resort to a screenshot, or print it to a PDF file. Adjust the browser zoom level to fit everything on it.

Also, the implementation of Gantt charts will change in the next major release, as the current software displays a note saying "This timelines module will be replaced by an interactive timelines view embedded into the work packages module. This module is being removed from OpenProject 7.0."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [R](https://www.r-project.org/), a statistics-centric programming language that is also often used to create charts and diagrams of various types:

- Free and open source software
- Cross-platform compatible
- There are [multiple R libraries to create Gantt charts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3550341)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using LaTeX, you may want to give [pgfgantt](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt?lang=en) a shot. You can do quite sophisticated charts with it, as seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209307/67042) for instance.

[image]