# Gantt chart & schedule based on project template

Tags: scheduling

My work consists of a number of nearly identical projects that I now need to make a gantt chart and schedule for when they each kick off.

Each of the projects is a fixed number of sequential tasks leading to a final synchronisation, but for each there are a few key differences:

- The number of initial threads that join at the end
- The start and deadline dates
- The people doing each of the individual tasks

I'd like to create a template that I could set the number of threads, have it create a little gantt chart view, and then start work on assigning tasks. Ideally it could integrate with email, so that when I assigned tasks the assignees got an email - bonus points if it integrates with outlook or AD so I don't have to import a long list of workers.

Firstly do any of the [Open Source Applications here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4542/open-source-gantt-chart-applications) do this?

If not, can it be done in MS Project, and does anyone know of a tutorial on how to achieve this?

Lastly, I mainly work on Windows 7, but if the best recommendation is Mac or Linux based I can use those too.